# What can a very short shutter speed do for me?

Tags: shutter-speed

Some camera have more shutter speed ,some are less.How it will effect Or use of that in photography.Which one considered as best

Answer (score 0):

Shutter speed affects several things...

1. It changes the amount of light that hits the sensor (or film). Used with aperture and ISO to give a proper exposure.
2. A faster shutter speed reduces the amount of motion blur that occurs when the photographer hand-holds the camera during exposure.
3. A faster shutter speed reduces the amount of motion blur that occurs when taking a picture of a moving subject.

The shutter speed you choose will depend on the subject and the effect you want to produce. You may want a slow shutter speed for velvety flowing water, or you may want a fast shutter speed for stopping the motion of motorcycle racers.

The key is not to think that there is an absolute 'best' shutter speed (or aperture) but to try to visualize what effect a particular shutter speed will have on a particular subject to create the effect you want.

Comment: Did you mean to say "... *slow* shutter speed for velvety flowing water..."?